# Making a simple timeline with Jquery map and moment js

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010, momentjs

I got a timeline working except for one small issue that I cant figure out. Its grouping my items by their dates but skipping the dates when there are no entries. I would like those dates to show but put a message saying "No entries to display".

For example:
If I select the date range from `2016-05-02` to `2016-05-04`

I would like to get:

```
Monday 2 May 2016
1   Test1
2   Test2
Tuesday 3 May 2016
No items to display...
Wednesday 4 May 2016
3   Test3
4   Test4
```

Heres a rough example of my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/vLdn68ko/15/

```
var items_by_date  = {}; // declare an object that will have date indexes
$.ajax({url:"/SomeUrlBeginninWithSlash/daterange/?$filter=(start_date ge '2016-05-02') and (end_date lt '2016-05-04')",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {

      data.d.results.map(function(item){
        var item_date = moment(item.Date).format('dddd D MMMM YYYY');
        // if the date index does not exist we need to declare it
        if(!items_by_date[item_date]) items_by_date[item_date] = [item];
        // else we can just push the item on that array
        else items_by_date[item_date].push(item);
      })

      console.log(items_by_date);
      // now you can render how ever you need to
      drawTable(items_by_date);
    }
});

function drawTable(data){
  $('#dataTable').html('');
  for(var d in data){ // d will be the date index
    $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">'+d+'</td></tr>');

    data[d].map(function(item){
      $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td>'+item.ID+'</td><td>'+item.Description+'</td></tr>');
    })
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically need to get the minimum date from your range, get the maximum and then fill your data with the days that have no entries. Its a bit ugly because you keep the date strings instead of dates, so have to convert but it works fine:

```
  var items_by_date  = {}; // declare an object that will have date indexes
  $.ajax({url:"/SomeUrlBeginninWithSlash",
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        data.d.results.map(function(item){
          var item_date = moment(item.Date).format('dddd D MMMM YYYY');
          // if the date index does not exist we need to declare it
          if(!items_by_date[item_date]) items_by_date[item_date] = [item];
          // else we can just push the item on that array
          else items_by_date[item_date].push(item);
        })

        fillEmpty(items_by_date);
        // now you can render how ever you need to
        drawTable(items_by_date);
      }
  });

  function fillEmpty(items_by_date){
    var dates = Object.keys(items_by_date).map(function(d){return new Date(d)})
    var minDate = new Date(Math.min.apply(null,dates))
    var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null,dates))
    while(minDate < maxDate){
      minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()+1)
      var key = moment(minDate).format('dddd D MMMM YYYY');
      items_by_date[key] = items_by_date[key] || [{ID:"",Description: "No items to display..."}]
    }
  }

  function drawTable(data){
    $('#dataTable').html('');
    Object.keys(data).sort(function(a,b){return new Date(a)-new Date(b)}).forEach(function(d){ // you actually need to show them sorted by day
        $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">'+d+'</td></tr>');
        data[d].map(function(item){
            $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td>'+item.ID+'</td><td>'+item.Description+'</td></tr>');
        })
      })
  }
```

Full Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vLdn68ko/18/

Comment: Thank you so much juvian, thats what I needed. Just one small question, is it possible to return HTML instead of making a null item entry? I have alot of entries in a table and making them all null makes it very clumsy for me. Would you have an easy way to simply ouput something like "<tr><td colspan='2'>No entries to display</td></tr>"?

Comment: @DanielEllison not sure I follow, what would be the expected input/output? If you don't want to keep the empty entries in items_by_date you can just delete the keys from data that have only 1 entry and its entry has no item.ID

Comment: What I was hoping to accomplish is to put a sort of condition that would check if the date has no item, then to return  $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">'+d+'</td></tr>'); and then  $('#dataTable').append('<tr><td colspan="2">No entries to display...</td></tr>');.

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you so much! That simplifies things for me.